# Link position tracking with GTM

Tags: jquery, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Is it possible to send the position of a link in an Google analytics event with GTM? I want to track which links on which position receive clicks in a dynamic top 10 overview. I've already checked the source of the page but there isn't any reference (class, text, id's etc) which could be used to specify the position. Is there an other way to determine on which position a link received x amount of clicks?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at Universal Analytics [Enhanced Ecommerce tracking](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce), specifically the [Product Impressions](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impressions) and [Product Clicks](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-clicks).

Basically, you specify a list, positions of products (doesn't have to be product specific), etc., and turn on Enhanced Ecommerce in GA. Then you'll have access to the Product List Performance report, where you'll have visibility into Position, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that would be an option but it aren't products. It are links to other websites. But basicly it comes down to that I need to change my sourccode to determine on which position a button is?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this depending upon the layout of your page.

Let's take the following example page:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>A Subheader</h3>
        <a href="page/to/link/to.html">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some paragraph Stuff</p>
        <a href="page/to/link/to.html">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that while the two links above are identical, their context within the DOM is not.

When you have a click trigger set up in GTM, the click event returns an object called "gtm.element". This object is the DOM representation of the element you clicked on.

Let's say a click was the 4th GTM event that happened on a page. Since arrays are zero-indexed it would be stored in dataLayer[3]. Then, in the browser console, you can access the gtm.element object by typing in the following:

```
dataLayer[3]['gtm.element']
```

That doesn't help us much since the two elements are identical, but the great thing about gtm.element is that we can traverse the DOM. Notice that The the link's parent divs have different first-child elements. The first link is preceded by an <h3> tag and the second link is preceded by <p> tag. In order to return this value you would want the "Parent Element's First Child's Tag Name" This is how you access that in the browser console:

```
dataLayer[3]['gtm.element'].parentElement.firstChild.tagName
```

In the GTM portal, the variable uses dot notation so you would define it like this:

```
{{Oldest Sibling TagName}} = gtm.element.parentElement.firstChild.tagName
```

Now that you have the "Oldest Sibling TagName" variable you can use it in a lookup-table variable to tell you which link was clicked on like So:

```
Input Variable = {{Oldest Sibling Tagname}}

Input: H3 - OutPut: "Top Link"
Input: P - Output: "Bottom Link"
```

Let's name this variable "Link Position"

Now all you have to do is use the "Link Position" variable in your GA tag under Category, Action, Label or whatever custom variable you want to track it under.